# Replace free text in a dataframe with a empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

what's the best way to replace any string in a dataframe?
The `SPECIAL_NEEDS` contains loads of free text and i cant delete the column/row as there is data in the other rows and columns. So i figured, why not just change the free text into a empty string ''
I'm currently working with this but its throwing errors?

```
df['SPECIAL_NEEDS'] = df['SPECIAL_NEEDS'].str.replace(str, '', regex=True)
```

Comment: could you provide a sample data? it's not clear what the question is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by free text? Any content should just be overwritten? In this case use:

```
df['SPECIAL_NEEDS'] = ""
```

Or just cases where the row value is a string?